# Consulta relación muchos a muchos laravel

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
Select cable.description, conector.descripcion
  From detalle_cable,detalle_conec,marca,modelo,cable,conector
    where detalle_cable.idmodelo=modelo.id and
          detalle_cable.idmarca=marca.id and
          detalle_cable.idcable=cable.id and
          detalle_conec.idmodelo=modelo.id and
          detalle_conec.idmarca=marca.id and
          detalle_conec.idconec=conector.id
          and marca.description like 'Aa%'
          and modelo.description like 'M80%' group by cable.description,
          conector.descripcion;
```

la quiero pasar a `eloquent` o `query builder`, hasta ahora va así pero me marca errores en l', anteriormente en otra consulta lo resolvi con un join pero en esta no me ah funcionado, marca esta relacionada con modelo, y asu vez estas están relacionadas con cable y conector, entre estos hay una relación de muchos a muchos

```
    $objects = DB::table('detalle_conec')
        ->join('marca', 'detalle_conec.idmarca', '=', 'marca.id')
        ->join('modelo', 'detalle_conec.idmodelo', '=', 'modelo.id')
        ->join('conector', 'detalle_conec.idconec', '=', 'conector.id')
        ->join('marca', 'detalle_cable.idmarca', '=', 'marca.id')
        ->join('modelo', 'detalle_cable.idmodelo', '=', 'modelo.id')
        ->join('cable', 'detalle_cable.idcable', '=', 'cable.id')
        ->where([
          ['marca.description', 'ilike', 'Aastra'],
          ['modelo.description', 'ilike', 'M8001'],
               ])
        ->select('conector.descripcion')

        ->select('conector.descripcion','cable.description')
        ->value('conector.descripcion','cable.description');
```

El error es

> PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42712]: Duplicate alias: 7 ERROR:  table name "marca" specified more than once")

Comment: Cuales son los errores?

Comment: Saludos, debes agregar el error que genera para poder darte una posible solución.

Comment: Pero el error es bastante claro.

Comment: @DiegoAvila ya coloque el error espero puedan asesorarme, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Saludos puedes hacer algo asi:

```
$objects = DB::table('detalle_conec')
        ->join('marca as marca1', 'detalle_conec.idmarca', '=', 'marca1.id')
        ->join('modelo as modelo1', 'detalle_conec.idmodelo', '=', 'modelo1.id')
        ->join('conector', 'detalle_conec.idconec', '=', 'conector.id')
        ->join('marca as marca2', 'detalle_cable.idmarca', '=', 'marca2.id')
        ->join('modelo as modelo2', 'detalle_cable.idmodelo', '=', 'modelo2.id')
        ->join('cable', 'detalle_cable.idcable', '=', 'cable.id')
        ->where([
          ['marca1.description', 'ilike', 'Aastra'],
          ['modelo1.description', 'ilike', 'M8001'],
               ])
        ->select('conector.descripcion')

        ->select('conector.descripcion','cable.description')
        ->value('conector.descripcion','cable.description');
```

La cuestión es que estas usando 2 **JOIN** con la misma tabla por ello debes usar los llamados **Alias** .

```
>join('marca as marca1', 'detalle_conec.idmarca', '=', 'marca1.id')
->join('marca as marca2', 'detalle_cable.idmarca', '=', 'marca2.id')
```

alli se ha agregado los alias prueba y comenta.

Comment: He eliminado mi respuesta para apoyar esta, pues no había revisado correctamente la pregunta. Por favor realiza lo mismo con la tabla modelo, tiene el mismo error.

Answer (score 0):

Va a tener exactamente el mismo error con "modelo", hay que agrupar esas *joins*:

```
$objects = DB::table('detalle_conec')
    ->join('marca', function($join){
        $join->on('detalle_conec.idmarca', '=', 'marca.id')
            ->on('detalle_cable.idmarca', '=', 'marca.id');
    })
    ->join('modelo', function($join){
        $join->on('detalle_conec.idmodelo', '=', 'modelo.id')
            ->on('detalle_cable.idmodelo', '=', 'modelo.id');
    })

    ->join('conector', 'detalle_conec.idconec', '=', 'conector.id')
    ->join('cable', 'detalle_cable.idcable', '=', 'cable.id')
    ->where([
      ['marca.description', 'ilike', 'Aastra'],
      ['modelo.description', 'ilike', 'M8001'],
    ])
    ->select('conector.descripcion','cable.description')
    ->groupBy('conector.descripcion','cable.description')->get();
```